# How to make a popup menu ignore key strokes (WM_MENUCHAR) in Win32 API

Tags: windows, winapi

I'd like to implement the following:

- Q key down, Q up: Perform some action.
- Q key down, left mouse button (LMB) down: Display a popup menu with more actions.

I'd like the popup menu to behave like a dropdown list, so that I can select items simply by hovering over them.

I use `TrackPopupMenu` to display the popup menu. The problem is that I get repeated [`WM_MENUCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646349(v=vs.85).aspx) messages while the Q key is still held down because of the keyboard repeat feature. I'd like to discard these messages, but I don't see a way to do that. Returning `MNC_IGNORE` still produces that beep which I'd like to avoid.

I'm perfectly fine with "not the intended usage, not possible" as an answer if that's the case.

Comment: I suppose it isn't impossible, you could return MNC_EXECUTE with a non-existing command identifier.  But you'll probably just break the menu when it has multiple items that start with the same letter.  There just isn't any reason to guess at something reasonable when the user does something unreasonable.  You'll guess wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with using the more traditional right-click button to display the popup menu? That is its primary purpose, after all.